# Reading only .csv file within a .zip from URL with Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, geopandas

There is a .csv file contained within a .zip file from a URL I am trying to read into a Pandas DataFrame; I don't want to download the .zip file to disk but rather read the data directly from the URL. I realize that pandas.read_csv() can only do this if the .csv file is the only file contained in the .zip, however, when I run this:

```
import pandas as pd

# specify zipped comma-separated values url
zip_csv_url = 'http://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2016/geo/ref/gaf/files-fichiers/2016_92-151_XBB_csv.zip'
df1 = pd.read_csv(zip_csv_url)
```

I get this:

```
ValueError: Multiple files found in compressed zip file ['2016_92-151_XBB.csv', '92-151-g2016001-eng.pdf', '92-151-g2016001-fra.pdf']
```

The contents of the .zip appear to be arranged as a list; I'm wondering how I can assign the new DataFrame (df1) as the only available .csv file in the .zip (as the .zip file from the URL I will be using would only ever have one .csv file within it). Thanks!

N.B.

The corresponding .zip file from a separate URL with shapefiles reads no problem with geopandas.read_file() when I run this code:

```
import geopandas as gpd

# specify zipped shapefile url
zip_shp_url = 'http://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2011/geo/bound-limit/files-fichiers/2016/ldb_000b16a_e.zip'
gdf1 = gpd.read_file(zip_shp_url)
```

Despite having a .pdf file also contained within the .zip, as seen in the image below:

[image]

It would appear that the geopandas.read_file() has the ability to only read the requisite shapefiles for creating the GeoDataFrame while ignoring unnecessary data files. Since it is based on Pandas, shouldn't Pandas also have a functionality to only read a .csv within a .zip with multiple other file types? Any thoughts?

Comment: `geopandas.read_file()` is not using pandas reading capabilities, but `fiona` and looks for shp by default.

Comment: Python [zipfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html) standard library will allow you to read your zip file and extract the csv file in a few line of code if needed (in order to feed it to `pandas.read_csv()`).

Answer (score 0):

```
import zipfile
import pandas as pd
from io import BytesIO
from urllib.request import urlopen


resp = urlopen(  YOUR_ZIP_LINK  )
files_zip = zipfile.ZipFile(BytesIO(resp.read()))
# files_zip.namelist()
directory_to_extract_to = YOUR_DESTINATION_FOLDER
file = YOUR_csv_FILE_NAME
with files_zip as zip_ref:
    zip_ref.extract(file,directory_to_extract_to)
pd.read_csv(directory_to_extract_to + file)
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to the StackOverflow community. Please read this helpful post to answer better. Please describe your solution and provide the input and output you tried to understand your answer better. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer